# How to send messages in robbiehanson XMPPFramework

Tags: xcode, xmpp, xmppframework

I can recieve messages fine from other clients, but I'm not sure hot to send messages. I've seen a few bits of code but I'm not sure where that code should be. in XMPPStream.m? and if so , where within?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your RootviewController.m :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject * currentUser = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:@"Hi"];

    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:currentUser.jidStr];
    [message addChild:body];

    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:message];

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks Yashesh, but I do need to say more than "Hi", don't I need to add something to the "XMPPStream.m" in order to bring up the iOS keyboard to type dynamically a message? Thanks for the information. I've been using JS in Titanium and this is my first project using native iOS code.

Comment: To bring keyboard up you don't need to write code for that , when you click on textfield then keyboard will bring up automatically , but to hide the keyboard you need to write code for that.

Comment: Would I need to put that in the main XMPPStream.m or place it in the RootviewController.m? Also I'm not seeing a text field when I type just the "Hi" when I click my contact. Do I need to change the StringValue?

Comment: Place it in RootViewController.m. This is the example of sending static message "Hi". For textview input u need to design your own UIViewController which should have textfield and send button to send message.

Comment: Ah okay, I may just wait till I make this library into a module in Titanium and then create the view from there. Thanks for the information Yashesh.

Comment: So just to be sure, I need to "setStringValue" to something in RootviewController.m then define it and then reference it in RootviewController.h

Comment: So just to be sure, I need to "setStringValue" to something in RootviewController.m then define it and then reference it in RootviewController.h

So something like [body setStringValue:sendStr]; then define what the "sendStr" is in a different pragma mark with something like 

sendfeild.text = [[NSUserDefaults...bla bla bla bla stuff stuff];

more code...more code
"@"synthesize sendfeild;

Then add to my RootviewController.h

"@"interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController 
{
  UITextField *sendfeild;


Dose that sound correct?